What does $\frac13-\frac15+\frac17+\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}-\frac1{17}+\frac1{19}+\frac1{23}-\frac1{29}+\frac1{31}-\dots$ equal?
All terms are reciprocals of odd primes:

Primes of form $4k + 1$ are subtracted.
Primes of form $4k - 1$ are added.
I find this in $\tt Euler's\ E596$.
He approximates the sum to be "almost exactly $= 0.334981$".
Summing  the first $104800001$ primes gives $0.3349764935584768$.
His method relies on the values of sums
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^n}=1-\frac1{3^n}+\frac1{5^n} - \cdots\quad
\mbox{for odd}\ n
$$
Euler ends with how unless the sum of this series is
known, this investigation "may have been undertaken in vain".

With our current mathematical understanding, how could we better approach this problem ( if Euler could not do it ) ?.

This is (9) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html, also https://oeis.org/A086239.

To the editor(s): Why is “All terms are reciprocals of” formatted with backticks? These are for preformatted text, e.g. forcode. Why is “Euler's E596” formatted as teletype text?
